# Why can't I subscribe to interval observable in component constructor? - Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that is a loading bar. This component gets rendered inside of an Angular Material dialog.

for whatever reason, I cannot seem to get any value from an interval observable in my constructor until after this component gets destroyed....

the constructor goes like this:

```
constructor(){
    interval(1000).pipe(
        tap(res => console.log(res))
    ).subscribe();
}
```

I don't actually get any values in my console until after the loader is essentially finished.

In another part of the application where each row of data is getting churned through, an auto-incremented value is getting passed into a subject of a service so I can get that value from the service here in this component.

That auto-incremented value is changing very quickly, so I want to get it on an interval. However, I can't even get the interval to play ball initially, so I am stymied there.

Any thoughts as to why this is happening?

Comment: Usually, any initial logic you want to handle in your component, you do it inside the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook, for that you need to implement `onInit`

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nvwwqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example.ts You would need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: I think it has to do with change detection from another service in the app. It's going to be hard to produce an example. I guess another question would be, would memory / script consumption by the browser ever be a reason why something like the above wouldn't work?

Comment: @Willie when the component is disposed are you unsubscribing from observables that you've manually subscribed to? Otherwise you might see strange behaviour/memory leaks